# Can the Apple Watch gracefully support this timesystem?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, time

At [The Natural Cycle Clock](https://CJSHayward.com/clock/clock.cgi), I try to implement an ancient timekeeping system, in which the day from sunrise to sunset is divided into twelve hours which are equal in length to other hours of that specific day, and the night from sunset to sunrise is divided into twelve hours, equal in length to other hours of that specific day, with the consequence that unless it's at an equinox or you're at the equator, hours of the day are not equal in length to hours of the night, and the length of an hour of one day is usually slightly different from the day before. (*Note to visitors: [The Natural Cycle Clock](https://CJSHayward.com/clock/clock.cgi) as a webpage is practically stone age, and no attempt has been made to polish it up.*)

Can the Apple Watch gracefully display a clock for this time system without getting an app into the store? Does it work, gracefully, to implement a nice clock for said system as a carefully tailored microsite and use it, or would such a microsite be relegated to second-class status because it's not one of the bundled options for timekeeping?

Comment: Note to someone who can create tags: Please create the tag 'iwatch' and apply it to this question.

Comment: Actually, the product is the Watch

Comment: @JonathanHayward, there is no need for an iWatch tag as 1) The product is called an Apple Watch. 2) There's an already existing [tag:apple-watch] tag

Comment: iWatch and Apple Watch are actually two different products made by two different companies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be great if the Apple Watch could. As of the current version, it cannot. However, future versions may allow this. The current developer terms do not allow for timekeeping apps. From the [iPhone in Canada](http://www.iphoneincanada.ca/news/timekeeping-apple-watch-apps-will-be-rejected-guidelines-update/) website:

> Under chapter 10, “User Interface,” developers will find a new entry,
>   10.7, which says “Watch apps whose primary function is telling time will be rejected.” This rule corroborates Gruber’s forecast: Apple
>   doesn’t want to give up the watch face to developers. Considering the
>   effort, the countless hours put into the 10 watch faces currently
>   available for the Apple Watch, and the new rule, you can forget about
>   custom watch faces anytime soon

.

Comment: Disagree with your point. It's not at all clear how such an App would be treated since it would not be doing "timekeeping" as most people know it -- the cadence of "beats" would be totally different in winter and summer.   Such an App might well be approved -- e.g., if it was part of an astronomy app; in the context of a fitness or sleep-cycle app, etc.

Comment: It may at that. I truly hope so. I am just remarking on the current state of things as I could investigate. If you find further documentation to the contrary please post as an answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to display content on the watch without an app. The Apple Watch does not have a web browser.